# Is there a validator for HTTP to show if my vendor's API is creating a poorly formed POST?

Tags: http, multipartform-data

I apologize if this isn't the right forum for this, but I couldn't figure out where this question fits in all the sites.  My vendor has an API for upload a file to a server, creating a POST with Content-Type: multipart/form-data.  My node.js express cannot parse the request, and when using other tools to generate upload requests the main difference I see, in Fiddler, is that there is one section between boundaries with absolutely no content.  E.g.:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=887c07d2-ff01-4eaa-b374-a807f9673742
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_15
Host: 192.168.1.109:3000
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2539

--887c07d2-ff01-4eaa-b374-a807f9673742
--887c07d2-ff01-4eaa-b374-a807f9673742
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

picture_178.jpg
--887c07d2-ff01-4eaa-b374-a807f9673742
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="folder"

whatever
--887c07d2-ff01-4eaa-b374-a807f9673742
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="picture_178.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

......JFIF.....H.H.....C.........................................
(etcetera)
```

I've looked at the relevant RFCs and I think this is not valid, but is there some tool to help me gain agreement on this to demonstrate to my vendor?  I know about the HTML validators, and other validators, but I couldn't find anything to validate the line protocol results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't know of any online validation tool, but the [multipart spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) demands parts between boundaries to be RFC 822 compliant messages. Since said RFC requires messages to have some whitespaces at least, an empty string does not suffice. Hence I believe, the example isn't a valid multipart message.